# sklearn feature_extraction fit parallelization

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm trying to build a vectorizer for a text mining problem. The used vocabulary should be fitted from given files. However, the number of files that will build the dictionary `vocabulary_` is relatively large (say 10^5). Is there a simple way to parallelize that?

**Update:** As I found out, there is a "manual" way... Unfortunately, it **only works for `min_df=1`** Let me exemplary describe what I do for two cores:
Split your input into two chunks. Train vectorizers (say vec1 and vec2), each on one core and on one chunk of your data (I used `multiprocessing.Pool`). Then,

```
# Use sets to dedupe token
vocab = set(vec1.vocabulary_) | set(vec2.vocabulary_)
# Create final vectorizer with given vocabulary
final_vec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab)
# Create the dictionary final_vec.vocabulary_ 
final_vec._validate_vocabulary()
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mllib`, the machine learning library included in `apache-spark` wchich will handle the distribution accross nodes.

Here's a tutorial on how to use it for feature extraction.

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html

You can also check the sklearn documentation on ***How to optimize for speed*** [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/performance.html) to get some inspiration.